# Changing Woocommerce My-Account Slug/Permalink

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce wordpress "My-Account" slug.

I'm attempting to change the .com/my-account/ slug to .com/account/

I can successfully do this through page editor and changing the slug, But once i have done that i lose the display of the dashboard.
Refer to photo's below.

[My-Account Slug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOJvQ.png)

[Account Slug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYFa6.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do the same,

1. You can change the slug from WP-Admin->Pages->My Account page.
2. By defining custom rewrite rule in the .htaccess file.

   ```
    function custom_rewrite_tag() {
      add_rewrite_tag('%myaccount%', 'my-account');
    } add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
   ```

Source: [Changing Woocommerce My-Account Slug/Permalink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688928/changing-woocommerce-my-account-slug-permalink)

Comment: I've looked at your answer to another question similar, Not sure where to place the rewrite rule?

Also, As in my question. I've stated i have already changed the slug. Refer to photo's. Thanks